# Can't find library header CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm importing admesh library to my cmake project, I've followed the INSTALL instructions from the file in root directory of admesh and it was copied in `usr/local/include` / `usr/local/lib`. So, I've added this in my CMakeList:

```
find_path(ADMESH_INCLUDE_DIR stl.h HINTS "/usr/local/include/admesh")
FIND_LIBRARY(ADMESH_LIBRARY NAMES admesh)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(ADMESH  DEFAULT_MSG  ADMESH_LIBRARY  ADMESH_INCLUDE_DIR)

IF(ADMESH_FOUND)
    message("admesh found")
    SET( ADMESH_LIBRARIES ${ADMESH_LIBRARY} )
ENDIF(ADMESH_FOUND)

include_directories(${ADMESH_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE  admesh ${ADMESH_LIBRARIES})
```

but when I tried to build it give me this error:

```
fatal error: 'admesh/stl.h' file not found
#include <admesh/stl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It prints `admesh found` so I think that there is something wrong in my CMakeList. How can I fix it?

Comment: [`find_package_handle_standard_args`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html?highlight=find_package_handle#command:find_package_handle_standard_args) is meant for use in a find script not for direct use by someone importing the lib. `find_package` should be used assuming the lib does provide cmake configuration scripts...

Comment: now it says `ld: library not found for -ladmesh clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: What exactly is the full path to the lib? What does `ADMESH_LIBRARY` contain after `find_library`? Why are half of the commands you use all uppercase? (CMake examples usually use all lowercase for commands, but for commands the case doesn't matter.)

Comment: in the `usr/local/lib` there is the 'libadmesh.1.0.0.dylib' file. the `ADMESH_LIBRARY ` variable contains the correct path to that file. The upper ones there were copied from the repo, I'll switch it to lower case to ensure that will not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
find_path(ADMESH_INCLUDE_DIR admesh/stl.h HINTS "/usr/local/include")
```

or

```
find_path(ADMESH_INCLUDE_DIR admesh HINTS "/usr/local/include")
```

Usually `/usr/local/include` is in the system search include paths, thus all lines until `arget_link_libraries(project PRIVATE admesh)` can be removed.

Comment: now it says `ld: library not found for -ladmesh
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Your question was about `fatal error: 'admesh/stl.h' file not found`, that seems to be resolved. If you have other issues, please ask a new question.